# reading a line from a file and put it in a string (with fstream)

Tags: c++, file, fstream, getline

i want to read a file and put each line in a string (each line contains a single word)
i've used `getline` but it doesn't work neither does the `>>` command.
here's my code:
(i'm using visual studio)

```
string device_kind;
ifstream bank_info;
bank_info.open ("acquirer.info");

bank_info >> device_kind; //fails to compile
getline (bank_info, device_kind); //also fails

bank_info.close();
```

Comment: "fails to compile" isn't a very useful problem description. Your compiler provides more details than that.

Comment: `bank_info >> device_kind` shouldn't fail to compile. Or do you mean it does not work like you wanted it? Make sure you have included `<string>`!

Answer (score 0):

use `bank_info.geline(device_kind,size)`
getline is member function of ifstream so use it with . operator.

Comment: There's also a global C++ function `std::getline()`, the one the OP is using. The member function version you're using is for C-style arrays, that line of code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [my code on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/j0JPAw)

```
string device_kind;
ifstream bank_info("acquirer.info");

if(!bank_info.bad())
{
   getline(bank_info, device_kind);
   cout << device_kind;
}

bank_info.close();
```

It outputs the first line of the file for me, so it should also work for you!

If you want to read your file in a `vector<string>` of lines, you can do it, like I do here: http://ideone.com/qNW5N9